# Circuit controlling 6 leds

Tags: led, digital-logic

I want to build a circuit with logic gates and flip-flops, in each clock which will turn 6 LEDs in
the following sequence: 1 - 6, 2 - 5, 3 - 4, 4 - 5, 4 - 6, 5 - 6, (repeat). I have spent 2 days in order to get perfect design. Does anybody can help me for making the perfect structure.
[image]

Comment: Where is your truth table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple process you can follow for your design:

#### 1. Identify the number of states

From what you have said it appears you have 6 states - 6 different outputs in your sequence before it repeats. So build a counter which counts up from 0 to 5 then resets as it reaches 6. This will be your input.

There are different counters you can make - a 3bit binary counter can go from 0-7 so you would just need reset on 6 logic. You could make a counter which is just 6 registers in a cycle where only one is ever high - the 1 then cycles round (one-hot). And so on.

#### 2. Work out your outputs

In you case you have 6 LEDs. These are your outputs. So you need to draw a Truth Table for each output which relates the output to each of your inputs (see 1.).

#### 3. Determine the Logic

Next once you have your truth tables, you need to determine the logic needed to make that mapping. The easiest way to do this is to build a Karnaugh Map for each LED. Use the map to determine the logic that maps the input counter to the LED value for each of the states.

#### 4. Simplification

It may then be possible to reduce the logic by simplifying the result from the Karnaugh Maps. This can be done by looking at the Boolean expressions and applying various rules of Boolean algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, hope it will be helpful. But all I need is scheme of logic gates for controlling 6 LEDs(more related to 3rd part of your answer).

Comment: If that is all you need all you have to do is follow the steps layed out for you. For questions like this we (the EE-SE contributors) tend to prefer to show the way, not the final solution. As a teacher, I strongly support this way of answering.

Comment: I'm Computer Science student, to do all the steps you told I need days to study them all. The reason why I asked this here is that I need to finish the task tomorrow.

Comment: @IslamSabr I say this in the nicest possible way, but it is *your* assignment which means if we just give you the full solution you will be submitting our work as your own. Even if you ignore the plagiarism aspect of that, how is it fair on all the other students in your class who have gone to the effort of coming up with the solution themselves. Your lecturer should have provided you with all of the notes required to do the exercise. You can ignore step 4 if you don't have time, but the first two steps will not take long and for step 3 there are many tutorials which you can follow.